# Getting empty view and blank navigation bar when I use popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm writing an iPhone app that is based on a UINavigationController. I'm pulling data from a server that sometime returns bogus links. I open each link by pushing a webview viewcontroller. I want to be able to include some error handling. I know if the link is no good. So I want to be able to pop the webview view controller as soon as I know that my webview has encountered an error.

Currently, I've tried using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I then get a Navigation bar with nothing displayed in it, but if I click where the "back" button should be it operates appropriately. The title pops up when I click where the "back" button should be. The view where the viewcontrollers usually display there content is blank white too even though I'm popping back to a UITableViewController.

I've tried this as a workaround:

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[nav.visibleViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

I've checked the viewControllers array in the UINavigationController and it has the right viewcontrollers in it (ie it has removed the viewcontroller for the webview).

I also tried putting code in the viewWillAppear of the viewcontroller I'm popping back to, but the method is never getting called.

I'm looking for a way to force the UINavigationController to reload the same way that you can call `reloadData` on a UITableView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to push the view controller?

Comment: Sure. [self.navigationController pushViewController:wv animated:YES]; where wv is the webview viewcontroller that has been alloc, init'ed and then passed the url it is loading.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something like this on my app where I was using a navigation bar I added in Interface Builder on the root view of a navigation controller and then programmatically creating the nav bar and its subviews for the second view. When I would pop the second view to return to the first view I would hide the self.navigationcontroller bar which would show the white space underneath until the IB nav bar of the previous view appeared. To fix this I decided to stick with programmatically creating all my navbars which fixed the issue for me.

TL;DR - if you are using both IB and programmatically made navbars this can happen when popping views, stick with one or the other for all the navbars yo